# Lining attributes up with features when creating shapefile using PyShp?

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I used the Python Module Pyshp to select particular census blocks from the Census's shapefiles and package these into a single shapefile. However when I add this data into ArcMap and right click to identify blocks, I get attributes for multiple blocks nowhere near the intended block. At first I assumed I had written my script in a way that misaligned the records and shapes objects in pyshp, but when I read this shapefile back into python, everything appears to be aligned correctly (i.e. I can look up the record I want and find the correct shape at the same index and vice versa).

Does anyone have a suggestion as to the next place I can look to try and solve my problem?

Here is the class I built to do this. The order of operations is to call load to get a particular zip file from the census, use add_blocks to collect any that match my list and add them to the writer object, and then write_shapefile to save whatever I've collected.

```
class CensusConnection:

    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = ''
        self.ftp_path = 'ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/TABBLOCK/2010/'
        self.reader = None
        self.writer = shapefile.Writer()

    def load(self,state_fips, county_fips = ''): 
        '''Use me to load all blocks into a folder in pwd that match state FIPS, or state FIPS plus county FIPS.'''
        #import data and set up reader object
        self.file_name = 'tl_2010_' + state_fips + county_fips + '_tabblock10' 
        tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        if not os.path.exists('tl_2010_' + state_fips + county_fips + '_tabblock10'):
            print 'Retrieving ' + self.ftp_path + self.file_name + '.zip...'
            sock = urllib2.urlopen(self.ftp_path + self.file_name + '.zip')
            memfile = io.BytesIO(sock.read())
            ZipFile(memfile, 'a').extractall(tempdir + "/" + self.file_name)
        self.reader = shapefile.Reader(tempdir + "/" + self.file_name + "/" + self.file_name)
        self._dump()
        #set up writer object to match reader
        self.shapes = self.reader.shapes()
        self.fields = self.reader.fields
        self.records = self.reader.records()
        self.writer.fields = self.fields

    def _dump(self):
        if (os.path.exists(self.file_name)):
            shutil.rmtree(self.file_name)

    def add_blocks(self, block_keys): 
        '''Take a block key, find that block and add shapefiles to the writer object'''
        '''Block Key = StateFIPS + CountyFIPS + TractID + GroupID + BlockID (15 digit)'''
        fields = self.reader.fields
        records = self.reader.records()
        for index in range(len(records)):
            if(records[index][4] in set(block_keys)):
                self.writer.shapes().append(self.reader.shapes()[index])
                self.writer.records.append(self.reader.records()[index])

    def write_shapefile(self,dir_name):
        if(len(self.writer.records)>0):
            if(os.path.exists(dir_name)):
                shutil.rmtree(dir_name)
            os.mkdir(dir_name)
            self.writer.save(dir_name+"/"+dir_name)
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but the most likely explanation is that your script is wrong. Can you post it?

Comment: just posted it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just curious if you need to add '()' to records: self.writer.records().append(self.reader.records()[index])

Comment: It looks like a quirk of this module that writers are accessed directly as a list rather than through a method like you do with shapes(). A tutorial I found seems to do the same thing (see the code from that tutorial here:  http://www.cimms.ou.edu/~lakshman/spatialprogramming/chapter03_basicgis/waterbodies.py )

Comment: Are you sure you have the right coordinate system?

Comment: I did just confirm that the census uses NAD1983 so yes. The blocks definitely appear in the correct places (they line up well with features of the basemap as they should). Just the attributes are off. It actually appears to be somewhat consistent (all of the blocks in CT for example will show up with attributes from MD)

Comment: I see one issue with the script which is a quirk of the module.  When you copy the fields from the Reader object, you need to cast them to a list. See this example: http://geospatialpython.com/2010/12/subsetting-shapefile-by-attributes.html

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I wasn't very scientific because I tried your tip and a few other things all at once, and now things seem to be working. In particular, using the built-in function 'reader.shape(index)' instead of 'reader.shapes()[index]' sped things up enormously! D'oh!

Comment: When you get a chance, I am hoping you can write up what you did to help future readers encountering the same problem with PyShp.  It is fine to answer your own question here.